# asp.net ListView sorting numerically

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, sorting, datatable

I have a list view which is bound to a DataTable source.
The sorting works, kinda.

For text is fine but not so much for numbers.

For example if I sort 1-12 descending I get 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,12,11,10,1.

How to get the proper sequence?

I am using:

```
lvPos.Sort("Position", SortDirection.Descending);
```

Comment: if you using IEnumerable datasource as list view you can use LINQ for sort and rebind.

Comment: that doesn't work I was doing it like that originally but this error happens: The data source 'reportObjectDataSource' does not support sorting with IEnumerable data. Automatic sorting is only supported with DataView, DataTable, and DataSet hence the DataTable which allows the sort.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I sort Integers in a listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214289/how-do-i-sort-integers-in-a-listview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're likely going to have to do the sorting yourself instead of relying on ListView's sort method.

If you're sorting just using code, this is very easy.  Just shove your DataTable into a DataView and use the DataView's Sort method.  Then bind to your DataView instead of your DataTable.

```
var view = new DataView(dtTable);
view.Sort = "Position"; //or "Position DESC"
lvPos.DataSource = view;
lvPos.DataBind();  //use lvPos.DataBind(true) to raise the "OnDataBinding" event.
```

If you're sorting from the ListView's sort methods (i.e. you have something in the page triggering the ListView.Sorting/Sorted events), then you would have to hook on to the Sorting event and cancel it.  Follow up with the previous technique of shoving the DataTable into a DataView (or re-use the DataView!), sort by the new expression, and rebind your data.

```
private void lvPos_Sorting(object sender, ListViewSortEventArgs args)
{
   var view = new DataView(dtTable);
   view.Sort = args.SortExpression;
   lvPos.DataSource = view;
   lvPos.DataBind();
   args.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the e.SortExpression; expression above. Does lvPos_Sorting get called when you set OnSorting="lvPos_Sorting"? where is e.SortExpression defined? aspx page?

Comment: My bad.  e.sortExpression should have been args.sortExpression. I've made the appropriate edit. And yes, lvPos_Sorting gets called if you put OnSorting="lvPos_Sorting" in the tag for your listview control. SortExpression is a member of ListViewSortEventArgs.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to actually set the data type like so:

```
table.Columns[0].DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
```

Now the sort actually sorts the items by value as ints, not as strings.

[See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)