# C# ListView Sort method doesn't sort numerical data Correctly

Tags: c#, listview, listviewitem

I have a listview with 3 columns i.e., column header names as "Files" , "File Date" and "File Size". I have data in string format as "afc_add_adjustment_1605550976284.out|12:23/Nov/16|52105". I further split down this string and store the strings in the 3 columns respectively.

```
string[] sTemp = null; 
sTemp = sFile.Split(new char[] { '|', '|' });
```

And the listview appear as seen below:

[image]

Now when I click on "Files" and "File Data" header, it sorts the data correctly in Ascending or Descending order but when I click on "File Size" header the sorting is not efficient.

My assumption is as the data under "File Size" is string (though it's numbers), the sorting is not working correctly even though compare method used is as per MS docs standard i.e.,

```
// Compare the two items
  compareResult = ObjectCompare.Compare(listviewX.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text, listviewY.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text);
```

**My question:**
How can I sort the data under "File Size" column in a correct way?. I tried converting the string data under "File Size" subitem to Int type before storing it in the listview subitem so that sorting can be efficient. But I didn't find any source where data is inserted as Int to subitems in the listview.

I also referred a similar question on stackoverflow but didn't find any appropriate solution.
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039700/asp-net-listview-sorting-numerically)

Please Guide me, thanks in advance :)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548312/sorting-a-listview-by-column/44469258?r=SearchResults&s=1|54.3247#44469258) should help

Comment: In the compare method first you should convert the text to numbers with int.Parse

Comment: @Mitulátbáti The compare method is called only when the Win Form is loaded, and the compare method compares only the first column which is "Files" and add the values accordingly to the ListView. The Form once when loaded can be clicked on the 3 column headers to sort it Ascending or Desc. If you mean to say use compare on "Fize size" instead of "FIles" column then that wouldn't be accurate as my first priority is to sort on "Files" column and if needed on "File Size" column.